# JAVA Input Comparison & Ignoring Negative Outcome

Tags: java, validation, loops

I'm new to JAVA and am struggling with a specific issue that I couldn't find an answer to so I decided to ask the good people of StackOverflow.

I am trying to build an ATM program. I have created an array of objects (The clients of the bank) with properties such as cardnumber, pin, balance, etc. And when any user will try and "log in" to the ATM he should type in his card number.

In the code below I tried to simulate the ATM going through the array of Clients and checking the input number with all the existing card numbers of each customer until it finds a match, and it works fine. The problem is that if it finds a match with client at position 10 it will display "Inexistent Card" 10 times before succeeding.

So I wanted to ask if there is a way for the program to ignore all these mismatches and only continue if it finds a match. And give me the "Inexistent Card" only when it finds 0 matches.

```
    for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        if (input.equals(clients[i].accountnumber)) {
            System.out.println("Welcome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Inexistent Card");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using a `found` boolean variable

```
boolean found = false;
for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    if (input.equals(clients[i].accountnumber)) {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

and then after the loop

```
if (!found) {
   System.out.println("Inexistent Card");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what you've written!

Think about it a bit more: You don't know the account doesn't exist until you've searched all the accounts and not found the one you want. You need to organise your code the same way. Just because `clients[0]` is not the one you are looking for, `clients[1]` might be, so you can't say "non existent" just yet...

Comment: I don't know if that's what you meant but I fixed it by adding a couple more lines- I moved the i++ from the fore loop in the else portion of the if statement and after it i added another if statement that checks whether the counter is greater than the length of the array and if it is then it prints the non-existent part

Comment: @AdrianDevder That sounds horrible. `i++` belongs in the for loop. The accepted answer is correct, but I didn't want to just give it to you. I'd rather explain and have you figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to achieve this:

```
int indexOfMatchingCard = -1;
for (... {
  if (match) {
     indexOfMatchingCard = current index
```

Afterwards, you can check if indexOfMatchingCard is >= 0; at the same time it tells you which of your cards matched. Just make sure to **not** reset that marker if you later find that other cards are not matching!

If you don't need to remember the matching index; you can use a simple boolean marker (which you initialize to false once; and change to true when on match).